# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i+1)^n}{2^n} = i+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have the following problem. I have to prove that

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(i+1)^n}{2^n}=i+1$$

$i$ = Imaginary unit

I can show that the series absolutely converges, but I don't know how to prove the result above. I know the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence, but unfortunately it's not allowed without prove that the formula is also valid for complex numbers.

I would appreciate every small hint.

Comment: It's a geometric series. You probably know the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know the formula. The problem is that I have the formula only proven for real numbers, not complex. So I'm searching for another way arround this dilemma

Comment: I see. The proof for complex numbers is probably exactly the same. If however the proof for the real case unexpectedly used the order on $\mathbb{R}$, it would have to be modified slightly.

Comment: First show it converges absolutely when $|z|<1$ so that you may arrange it into the proof for real numbers.  Then for $|z|=1$, the term test.

Comment: Well, if you're looking for a workaround, the value of $(i+1)^n$ is $2^k z$, for some natural number $k$ and $z \in \{\pm i, \pm 1, \pm (i+1), \pm (i-1)\}$, where $z$ depends on the congruence class of $n$ modulo $8$, and $k$ depends on the size of $n$. You can probably come up with explicit formulae for the real and imaginary parts, and collect terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a partial sum of the geometric series
  $$ S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N r^n = 1 + r + \ldots + r^N$$
Then
$$ (1-r) S_N = S_N - r S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N r^n - \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} r^n = 1 - r^{N+1}$$
so if $r \ne 1$, 
$$ S_N = \dfrac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r} $$
If $|r|<1$, we take the limit as $N \to \infty$ and get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \dfrac{1}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(i+1)^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i+1}2\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac{i+1}2}=1+i$$

Answer (score 4):

First note that $$\left|\frac{\mathrm{i}+1}2\right|=\frac {\sqrt{2}}2<1$$

Now
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\mathrm{i}+1)^n}{2^n}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}+1}2
\right)^n\\
&= \frac{1}{1-\frac{\mathrm{i}+1}2}\\
&= \frac{2}{1-\mathrm{i}}\\
&=\frac{ 2(1+\mathrm{i})}{(1-\mathrm{i})(1+\mathrm{i})}\\
&=1+\mathrm{i}
\end{align}
$$